# What's the policy for building a theme that doesn't support widgets/menus?

Tags: theme-development, menus, themes, widgets

I'm developing a minimalistic theme, and my plan is not to include menus or widgets in it.

The [Theme Review](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Review) page on wordpress.org states:

> Whether implementing required, recommended, or optional features,
>   Themes are required to support proper WordPress core implementation of
>   all included features.

This is quite fuzzy for me. Does this mean I have to include all WordPress core features? What's considered a core feature? Are Widgets and Menus core features?

Comment: You should ask this question on the [Theme-Reviewers mail-list](http://lists.wordpress.org/mailman/listinfo/theme-reviewers). The short answer is: yes, menus and widgets are core features. No, you are not required to implement those features in your Theme. But if you choose to implement them, then you **must** support the core implementation.

Comment: @ChipBennett as an answer please. This technically _is_ on topic here, despite official channel existence.

Comment: I disagree that Theme Review guidelines are on-topic for WPSE, but that is a discussion for Meta.